# How to deep clone a UIElement class in silverlight

Tags: c#, silverlight, xaml, reflection

So the XamlWriter is only available in WPF, not silverlight.

How can I achieve the same effect?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Silverlight XamlWriter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1254443/silverlight-xamlwriter)

Comment: @JMK, I also looked into that. But that's not the droid i'm looking for :p

Comment: ha fair enough, good luck :)