# The name 'XamlWriter' does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#, windows-10, xamlwriter

I'm developing a universal windows application (on windows 10), with a .NET framework 4.5.2

I'm trying to clone a xaml object using 'XamlWriter' and 'XamlReader', but it seems visual studio has no reference to this class. I'm getting:

> The name 'XamlWriter' does not exist in the current context

I've also noticed my visual studio has no `System.Windows.Markup` namespace (which contains 'XamlWriter' and 'XamlReader'), only `System.Windows.Input`.

I've searched the web (and here of course), but couldn't find any answers. I would be grateful for any clue.

Thanks.

Comment: Well if you're developing a UWA, you don't get access to all the WPF types as far as I'm aware... they're effectively separate frameworks.

Comment: oh, I wasn't aware of that, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The `XamlWriter` and `XamlReader` classes are only available in the full .NET framework stack, i.e. WPF, however, it's not implemented for UWA or Silverlight.

There are some workarounds for that, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1274375/75500) for example.